# FFmpeg как сделать качественный gif с небольшими затратами по времени и памяти PHP?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Есть раскадровка 25 кадров\с - около 100-200 кадров. Тестировал сборку GIF в FFmpeg через PHP
Сначала делал так:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -pattern_type glob -i '".$dir. 'frame_*.png' ".$dir. 'frames.gif
```

Очень быстро и очень мало памяти ест. Главный минус это какие то диагональные точки, которые очень заметны и образуют некие маленькие ромбики по все картинке.

Пробовал так:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -pattern_type glob -i '".$dir. 'frame_*.png' -filter_complex '[0:v] fps=25,split [a][b];[a] palettegen [p];[b][p] paletteuse' ".$dir. 'frames.gif
```

Качество хорошее и скорость сборки не долгая. Кратковременно затрачивает до **200мб** памяти оперативной. Но есть какой то косяк - гиф собирается с потерей кадров. Где то  65 кадров собираются и всё. Как только убираешь фильтры палитген и палитюз - все нормально. С чем связано такое поведение не понимаю, именно ровно 65 кадров обрабатывает и заканчивает работу - каждый раз.

Дайте советы по **ffmpeg** для хорошего результата с малыми жертвами в виде скорости и памяти. 
И может кто знает почему с **палитген и палитюз** так происходит и анимация собирается не полностью?

Comment: Предположу, что paletteuse не может начать свою работу, пока palettegen не закончит создание палитры, и из-за этого на [b] копятся кадры и жрут память. Возможно, и из-за этого как следствие всё упирается в 65 кадров, но не проверял. Мне кажется, будет правильнее запускать ffmpeg два раза: первый раз palettegen, а второй paletteuse с палитрой из первого ffmpeg. Я себе так гифки делал — вроде всё нормально было (хотя точные скорость и память не замерял)

Comment: @andreymal раздельно создаётся но жрёт память так же. Да и скоростью такой метод (с палитген и палитюз) не блещет. 130 кадров 950х950 гиф делает около 10-13 секунд.
Идеально было бы если бы собиралось за 1-2 секунды как первый вариант. По сути в результате минус только этот ковёр из пикселей в виде ромбиков. Убрать бы как то этот эффект, без потери скорости.

Comment: так он там нигде не упирается в то, что памяти выделить больше не получается, поэтому все что влезло (65) скидывает в результат, а остальное лесом?